# using root to mkdir in another users home directory

Tags: permissions, directory

having a bit of a difficult time trying to create a folder under another user's `/home/devuser1/pubic_html` folder. I'm trying to avoid using `sudo` and looking for an alternative. The permissions on the said folder reads as:

```
drwxr-s--- 2 devuser1  www-data 4096 Apr 28 19:40 public_html
```

Alternatively, assuming I use the `sudo` prefix, what would be the implications be? I've read that it's bad practice to use `sudo` to make a folder. After the new folder is created, I'm still changing the ownership of it to the user in question. Example:

```
chown -vR devuser1:www-data /home/devuser1/public_html/$vhost
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`sudo -u [username] mkdir /home/[username]/public_html/[folder_name]` works fine.

From what I can see the permissions and ownership is the same if I were to log in as the same user and create the folder under `public_html`.

You can also call `su -c "mkdir /home/[username]/public_html/[folder_name]" [username]`

Comment: When you run `sudo -u USERNAME mkdir DIRNAME`, you are executing the `mkdir` command as the user `USERNAME`. This isn't exactly equivalent to logging in as `USERNAME`, because logging in also implies setting environment variables and so on, but it's the part that matters, namely executing a process as a particular user.

Comment: Also that user might not have permission.

Answer (score 45):

With `install`, you can create a directory with a specific owner, group, and mode:

```
install -d -o <user> -g <group> -m <mode> <path>
```

Comment: `% sudo install -d -o <user> -g <group> -m <mode> <path>` for creating the directory in a `<path>/../` owned by _root_, for instance

Comment: One potential issue with this is it won't set the specified ownership on parent dirs it creates, only the last path segment. That's the behavior I'm seeing in version 8.32 on Rocky 9.

Answer (score 1):

Given those permissions, only the owner of the directory or the super user can create subdirectories.

The only way that you could avoid use extra privileges to create the folder is change the ownership to yourself (with `sudo`), create the subdirectory and finally return the ownership to the owner, but doesn't look like a good solution to me.

Comment: yea, tough one this. This is a silly question, but what are my options?

Comment: what about (as root) running the command as that user?: `sudo -u devuser1 mkdir /home/devuser1/public_html/test`. That's not the same as creating the folder with `sudo` is it?

`ls -al` reveals: `drwxr-sr-x 2 devuser1 www-data 4096 Apr 28 23:49 test
`

Comment: Maybe I'm being naïve, but I don't really see any evil in create a folder with `sudo` as long as you change the ownership after that.

Comment: From what `ls` reveals on the contents of the user's `public_html`, it appears as though changing ownership is not required, maybe permissions though.

Comment: I think I'm also being naïve in thinking this: I'm not creating the folder as `su`, instead I'm using it to *authenticate* myself as the user who is going to create the folder...does that make sense?

Comment: it does make sense, but unless you explain why is bad practice create folder with `sudo` and then change their ownership, I don't really see the point.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do a `mkdir -p /srv/postgres/data/mydir` but because

`drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Apr  7 08:26 srv` has owner `root`

neither `install -d -o <user> -g <group> -m <mode> <path>` [@user2313838](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186728/201876)

nor `sudo -u postgres mkdir -p /srv/postgres/data/mydir` works [@maGz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74054/201876)

The solution is to split it in two commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/postgres/data/mydir
sudo chown postgres:postgres /srv/postgres -R
```

Comment: `sudo install -d -o <user> -g <group> -m <mode> <path>` sets the owner/group/mode of the last component as `<user>`/`<group>`/`<mode>`.